Given a path to a logical volume get UUID without root
My question is simple, given a path to a logical volume: is it possible to get the UUID of the device it belongs to, without the need of root access in C? and if so, how would you approach this problem? (efficiency matters)

Is this focused on a particular operating system / file system? If so, please state which one. I'm guessing Linux.

Yes, Linux (althought, ideally I'd like to know if this is possible for other UNIX-based OSs). Specifically ext-based file systems, but as far as I know it doesn't really matter (even if the file system is an NTFS which provides a serial instead of uuid)

As long as your system has symbolic links in /dev/disk/by-uuid, you can match the device based on its UUID without sudo. This directory contains UUID-based links to block devices, which means you can find the UUID without accessing the device directly.
Example
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>


#define UUID_PATH_PREFIX "/dev/disk/by-uuid/"
#define UUID_PATH_LENGTH (18 + 36 + 1)  // Length of prefix + UUID + null terminator


int get_uuid_from(const char *volume_path, char *uuid_buf, size_t buf_size) {
    struct dirent *entry;
    DIR *dp = opendir(UUID_PATH_PREFIX);
    if (dp == NULL) {
        perror("opendir failed");
        return -1;
    }

    struct stat volume_stat, link_stat;
    if (stat(volume_path, &volume_stat) != 0) {
        perror("stat on volume_path failed");
        closedir(dp);
        return -1;
    }

    char path[UUID_PATH_LENGTH];
    while ((entry = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
        snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s%s", UUID_PATH_PREFIX, entry->d_name);

        if (stat(path, &link_stat) == 0 && link_stat.st_rdev == volume_stat.st_rdev) {
            strncpy(uuid_buf, entry->d_name, buf_size - 1);
            uuid_buf[buf_size - 1] = '\0';  // Ensure null termination
            closedir(dp);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    closedir(dp);
    return -1;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <volume_path>\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char uuid[37];  // UUID is 36 chars + null terminator
    if (get_uuid_from(argv[1], uuid, sizeof(uuid)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to retrieve UUID for %s\n", argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("UUID for %s: %s\n", argv[1], uuid);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

gcc -o get_uuid_test get_uuid_test.c

./get_uuid_test /dev/mapper/root

References

How get uuid of a device/partition in linux programatically?
libblkid only works with root and after running as root
how to get uuid of filesystem given a path?
Using libblkid to find UUID of a partition

Disclaimer
I have to admit this is an answer I got primarly from chat-gpt, evaluated and refined by me. While I did also found it was already answered here, eventually I decided to take the time and provide a complete answer with an example, in a new post.

my upvote for the solution. please read SO rules about generative AI posts.

This answer does not do what the question asks, i.e. determine UUID from mountpoint. For example, filesystem root (/) reports no UUID. Considering that this is a self-answered question, rephrasing the question might be in order.

@user30482 You are right, thanks for the catch, I'll fix it. I confushed the term mountpoint with the term "path to a logical volume".

Just to add to this. that fault of mine, was primarily a result of my original code where I do actually use a mountpoint or a random path as a starting point.

@user14063792468 Thanks. I read this instead, for some reason I got lost trying to find those specific rules in SO.

To add one more thing to the answer. In case someone is actually looking for a solution to any path: prior to this function call, the thing that has to do is simply check st_dev in /proc/mounts until it matches the one of your random-path. (or at least that worked for me in Linux)
